# IIS Redirecting to URL depending on locale settings from browser information

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

i want the IIS to redirect to a URL depending on the locale settings i get from the browser. I read about rewriting tables but i think thats not the proper way to solve that problem. The configuration of this funcionality should be only inside IIS but i am open for other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that implements  IHttpModule and then redirect based on the Request.UserLanguages value you receive:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule{
  public void Init(HttpApplication application){
      application.BeginRequest += 
        (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
    application.EndRequest += 
        (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
}

private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, 
     EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;
    var userLanguages = context.Request.UserLanguages;
   // Do something here based on the user languages
 }

private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{}
}
```

Then register it in your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
<httpModules><add name="MyModule" type="MyModule"/></httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh that helped me really out.